# Boost Unit Test turns all console text red permanently after failing check

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, console, console-application

I'm using Boost Unit Test and I have the following simple program:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

void test1()
{
  std::cout << "Here's test 1" << std::endl;
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(1, 2);
}

void test2()
{
  std::cout << "Here's test 2" << std::endl;
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(1, 1);
}

boost::unit_test::test_suite*
init_unit_test_suite(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  using namespace boost::unit_test;

  test_suite* ts1 = BOOST_TEST_SUITE("test_suite1");
  ts1->add(BOOST_TEST_CASE(&test1));
  ts1->add(BOOST_TEST_CASE(&test2));

  framework::master_test_suite().add(ts1);

  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the first test should fail and the second test should pass. Upon running this program with no arguments, everything works as expected, except that after the first test finishes, all console text becomes permanently red forever. This is the console output I'm seeing:

```
Running 2 test cases...
Here's test 1
c:/users/<redacted>/code/utils/cppscripts/testbed/testbed.cpp(8): error: in "test_suite1/test1": check 1 == 2 has failed [1 != 2]
Here's test 2

*** 1 failure is detected in the test module "Master Test Suite"
```

Not only is the `Here's test 2` text red, the console text color is still red even after the program has finished. I would prefer that only text pertaining to the particular test that failed is red, and I would most certainly prefer that Boost clean itself up and not force me to restart my commandline in order to get white text again. (Red on black is hard to read.)

Also, please do not suggest using the `--color_output` argument to turn off all color completely. That's not the answer I'm looking for.

I'm on Windows using Boost 1.67 with Visual Studio 2017. I notice the issue when running the test executable on both Windows command prompt and Windows powershell. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

This is likely due to a buggy terminal emulator OR a mismatch between the terminal emulation and the reported capabilities ([termcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap)).

You can try

- mintty
- ConEmu
- Terminator (more here https://alternativeto.net/software/mintty/)

If you're using this inside an IDE, e.g. VsCode or Clion, report a bug at their trackers.

At least on linux, there is no such issue:

[image]

Retest with full outputs:

[image]

Comment: I'm noticing this issue on both Windows command prompt and Windows powershell. And as you said, I'm not noticing the issue on Linux. I do find it odd that it wouldn't work on either of these given they're built into Windows. I'll look at some of the other options, though.

Comment: It's about the compatibility. Not all terminal s have the same capabilities. If they are wrongly assumed or wrongly reported there will be miscommunication. E.g. when you use a terminal emulator you frequently have to set TERM=vt100 or TERM=screen-256color or TERM=os2ansi or TERM=win32 etc. I would compare with _different terminals_ (likely PowerShell is running in the same terminal as the other shells you used). I (think** I heard Windows 10 is getting a brand nnew terminal implementation that is MUCH better. Finally.